# Selenium code to open facebook messenger and send a message

Tags: java, facebook, selenium

I'm just starting to learn a little bit of Selenium scripting (in Java). Currently I'm trying to open a chat box in Facebook and send a message.
I have gotten up to being able to open the chat box through selenium, however I can't figure out how to actually type things into the text box.
Currently here is my code:

```
import org.openqa.selenium.*;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;

public class practice {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
      System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:/max/chromedriver.exe");

      WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
      driver.get("http://facebook.com/login/");
      driver.manage().window().maximize();
      driver.findElement(By.name("email")).sendKeys("myemail@yahoo.com");
      driver.findElement(By.name("pass")).sendKeys("myPassword");
      driver.findElement(By.id("loginbutton")).click();
      driver.findElement(By.name("mercurymessages")).click();
      driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("a[href*='https://www.facebook.com/messages/conversation-8148306']")).click();
     // This has worked randomly. Sometimes the driver will work and open the chat box. Sometimes it will say element not found. I didn't include the full link of the conversation because apparently you don't have to. And it has worked like this in the past.
}
}
```

My current issue I'd like resolved is: why does this only work sometimes, and how do i find the text box area on the chat box? I did an Inspect Element and the chat box is very odd. It doesn't have anything like an id or a name, so i can't do By.id, or By.name. I can't figure out how to do it with By.cssSelector. This is what the inspect element for the text box looks like:

```
textarea class="uiTextareaAutogrow _552m" data-ft=".... more stuff here" onkeydown=" more stuff here" style= "more stuff here."
```

Comment: try using xpath!! element is not found because the css selector code is wrong

Comment: Why does it work sometimes then? Okay, I will try xpath.

Comment: "... starting to learn ... Selenium ... in Facebook" <- probably one of the most frustrating things you can do! This is a very complicated website, with lots of AJAX, and active automation deterrents. You should pick something easier to learn on.

Comment: you can skip several extra steps by opening directly the friend's messaging URL: `driver.get("https://www.facebook.com/messages/t/FRIEND_NAME")` - after login you will be redirected to the page with the input box already visible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to learn Xpath and how to create Relative xpath.The xpath for the textarea

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//textarea[@class='uiTextareaAutogrow _552m']"));
```

Anyhow I've made few changes that Include instead of clicking on some other message.It will create a new message and send to your friend

```
driver.findElement(By.name("mercurymessages")).click();

    //wait for 20 seconds 
    WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 20);
    wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.id("u_0_5")));
    driver.findElement(By.id("u_0_5")).click();//To click on Send a New Message Link

    //To enter a name into the to field 
    wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//input[@class='inputtext textInput']")));
    WebElement friendName = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@class='inputtext textInput']"));

    friendName.sendKeys("Deep");//Change it with your friend name

    //wait for the user list to appear
    wait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//li[@class='user selected']")));
    friendName.sendKeys(Keys.ENTER);

    WebElement messageBox = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//textarea[@class='uiTextareaAutogrow _552m']"));
    wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOf(messageBox));
    messageBox.sendKeys("Hi there");

    messageBox.sendKeys(Keys.ENTER);
```

Comment: Wow i didn't even think of your method (Sending a new message). The u_0_5 part ended up being u_0_4. Also, the input of the friendName doesn't work - for the class, it should be clearfix but for some reason it won't work. (Can't find the element).

Comment: Also, for the sending a new message where you type in a friend's name, when I looked at the inspect element of it, it has many different classes. For example, it goes from fbNubFlyoutHeader -> _1sk5 -> _1sk6 -> _54_v -> clearfix. All of those classes highlight the same thing (The "To: ") text box

Comment: I've ran it 10 times and it worked perfectly.The friend's name textbox is deep inside just go to the inner most level and you'll find the input tag

Comment: u_0_4 is the message icon. u_0_5 is the Send new message link

Comment: @needhelpwithR check the edited content .I've added wait Functionalities as well to make the script stable

Comment: Used your code - there is no such element called 'inputtext textInput'. Was I supposed to change that? Also the u_0_4 is the send new message link for me, at least. I tried u_0_5 and it didn't work

Comment: `<div class="clearfix uiTokenizer uiInlineTokenizer"><div class="tokenarea hidden_elem"></div><div class="uiTypeahead" id="js_h"><div class="wrap"><input type="hidden" autocomplete="off" class="hiddenInput"><div class="innerWrap"><input type="text" class="inputtext textInput" aria-label="" placeholder="" data-placeholder="" aria-expanded="false" aria-labelledby="u_0_2p" tabindex="0" style="width: 25px;"></div></div></div></div>` check this This is from the page

Comment: and that is not element, it's input element with classname `inputtext textInput` and When referring other person make sure you put @personName so that the person willbe notified.else they dont know whether you've said anything or not

Comment: How can i copy and paste the inspect element thing to here? Mine is different from yours.

Comment: If on chrome rightclick the element in developer tools and copy

Comment: <div class="clearfix uiTokenizer uiInlineTokenizer"><div class="tokenarea hidden_elem"></div><div class="uiTypeahead" id="js_2l"><div class="wrap"><input type="hidden" autocomplete="off" class="hiddenInput"><div class="innerWrap"><input type="text" class="inputtext textInput" aria-label="" placeholder="" data-placeholder="" aria-expanded="false" aria-labelledby="u_0_2a" tabindex="0" style="width: 25px;"></div></div></div></div>

Comment: The selenium is lagging my computer quite a bit. I wanted to try doing a for loop in java where it prints the numbers 0 to 100 to my friend (lol) just to show im actually doing selenium. however, it is very slow and lags my computer a lot. should i set the WebDriverWait to a lower value?

Comment: Put the last two lines in for loop `for(int i=0;i<100;i++){ messageBox.sendKeys("Hi there"+i);

    messageBox.sendKeys(Keys.ENTER);}`This is going beyond the question's content.I guess I will stop here

Comment: I know how to do a for loop. I did the loop but it is very slow and it makes my computer slow.

Comment: Is there any new approach in latest FB message sending? Coz, i am stuck with sending data to message box now.

Answer (score 0):

Hi pal hope this gonna help you:

there is a method called `By.className` so in order to find elements without an id or a name you can use this method, the thing it's that sometimes the class name of the element it's used in other elements, so be aware of the uses in the current page, if you are lucky and the class name is unique then you can use it :)

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:/max/chromedriver.exe");

      WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
      driver.get("http://facebook.com/login");
      driver.manage().window().maximize();
      Thread.sleep(5000);
      driver.findElement(By.name("email")).sendKeys("myemail@yahoo.com");
      driver.findElement(By.name("pass")).sendKeys("myPassword");
      driver.findElement(By.id("loginbutton")).click();
      Thread.sleep(5000);
      driver.findElement(By.name("mercurymessages")).click();
      Thread.sleep(7000);// here you have to use ExpectedConditions in order to verify that the elemnt  it´s "clickable"


      driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("a[href*='https://www.facebook.com/messages/conversation-8148306']")).click();

          Thread.sleep(5000);
      WebElement mssgbox = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("textarea[class*='uiTextareaAutogrow _552m']"));
      mssgbox.click();
        mssgbox.sendKeys("hi");
```

hope this help you.

and some times elements in the pages changes so use `ExpectedConditions` to be sure the element its on the page

Comment: Hey at first I tried using the uiTextareaAutogrow _552m inside the className, but it said that "compound class names are not allowed." I deleted the _552m and continued with the code and the driver ended up writing the text inside the status box - the one that says "What's on your mind?" at the top of your newsfeed.

Answer (score 0):

How to send message to your friend on Facebook:: Using Selenium WebDriver

```
// Find Username and Enter
        driver.findElement(By.id("email")).sendKeys("Email");
        System.out.println("Email");

        // Find Password and Enter
        driver.findElement(By.id("pass")).sendKeys("Password");
        System.out.println("Password");

        // Click Login
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(2, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='u_0_q']")).click();
        System.out.println("LogIn Successfull");
        Thread.sleep(2000);

        // Message
        driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='u_0_f']/a/div")).click();
        driver.findElement(By
                .xpath(".//*[@id='u_0_f']/div/div[3]/div/div[1]/div/div/ul/li[2]/a/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/div[1]/strong/span"))
                .click();

        Thread.sleep(2000);

        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@class='_1mf _1mj']//following :: div[11]")).click();
        Thread.sleep(2000);
        WebElement sendmsg = driver
                .findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='_1ia']/descendant::div[@class='_5rpu' and @role='combobox']"));
        sendmsg.sendKeys("Just testing: using selenium webdriver" + Keys.ENTER);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
                IWebElement messageBox = driver.FindElement(By.ClassName("_1mj"));

                messageBox.SendKeys(string.Format("{0} Do not try to scam people anymore!!!", iteratia++));

                messageBox.SendKeys(Keys.Enter);
```

Using C#
I can access the message textbox to insert the message with the first line of code. The second line is inserting the message. The third line is sending it.

Result:

[image]